# What is closed form of f when $f(n)=\frac{1}{f(n-1)}+f(n-2), f(2)=1, f(1)=0$?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations, closed-form, recursion

I've tried to solve this problem this way with characteristic equation:

[What is the closed form of the $f$ with $f(1)=1$, $f(2)=7$ and $f(n)=7f(n-1)-12f(n-2)$ ($n\ge 3$)?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3292475/what-is-the-closed-form-of-the-f-with-f1-1-f2-7-and-fn-7fn-1-12f/3292482)

$F_n=x^n$

$x^{n-2}(x^2-\frac{1}{x}-1) = 0$

$x^3-x-1 = 0$

but this equation have only one real solution and i'm confused if i can further use this method or not.
Any ideas?

Comment: Hello, welcome to the Mathematics Stack Exchange. This method is _only_ valid for linear, homogeneous recurrent equations. You have to use other tools to find the closed form of this function.

Comment: As @LucasHenrique said, that method only works for linear homogeneous recurrent sequences. I just want to add that in some of those cases, the characteristic polynomial has complex (non-real) roots but that is NOT an issue. So, even if you were working with a recurrence where the characteristic polynomial method applies, it shouldn't confuse you if the polynomial has complex roots.

Comment: Numerically, $\frac{f(n+1)}{f(n)}$ seems to tend to $\approx \pi$ and $\approx \frac1\pi$, alternatingly. I therefore suspect some relations to elliptic integrals and AGM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following @Cesareo's answer and checking the initial values, we find that
$$ \tag1f(n)f(n+1)=n-1$$
for all $n$.
With the double factorial
$$ n!!=\prod_{0\le k<\frac n2}(n-2k)=\begin{cases}
m!\cdot 2^m,&n=2m\\
\frac{n!}{m!^2\cdot 4^m},&n=2m+1\\
\end{cases},$$
we can see that (at least for $n\ge 3$)
$$ f(n)=\frac{(n-2)!!}{(n-3)!!}$$
fits the recursion because it correctly produces
$$ f(3)=\frac{1!!}{0!!}=1$$ and makes
$$ f(n+1)f(n)=\frac{(n-1)!!(n-2)!!}{(n-2)!!(n-3)!!}=n-1.$$

Answer (score 2):

Hint.

Making
$$
G(n) = f(n)f(n-1)
$$

we have the recurrence

$$
G(n) -G(n-1) = 1
$$

with solution

$$
G(n) = c_0 + n
$$

and now from $G(2) = f(2)f(1) = 0 = c_0+2$ we have

$$
f(n)f(n-1) = n-2
$$

now as

$$
\cases{
f(n+1)f(n) = n-1\\
f(n)f(n-1) = n-2
}\Rightarrow f(n+1) = \frac{n-1}{n-2}f(n-1)
$$

with initial conditions $f(2)=1,\ f(3) = 1$ and the recurrence solution is

$$
f(n) = \frac{\left((\pi -2) (-1)^n+2+\pi \right) \Gamma \left(\frac{n}{2}\right)}{2 \sqrt{\pi } \Gamma \left(\frac{n-1}{2}\right)}
$$

Comment: Ah, that makes $\frac{f(n+1)}{f(n)}$ something like a Wallis product approximation for $\pi$ ...

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to MSE.

If you try the MATLAB code below

```
clc 
clear 
a(1)=0; 
a(2)=1; 
for i=3:30  
    a(i)=1/a(i-1)+a(i-2); 
   end;
plot(a)
```

then you will see the oscillatory behavior of the sequence.
Like this:
[image]

Are you sure that there is not a typo?

Comment: It looks like $O(\sqrt n)$ which makes sense, at least to leading order

Comment: Given one solution $f(n)$, another solution has $g(2n)=kf(2n),g(2n+1)=f(2n+1)/k$. There might be one value of $k$ that minimises the oscillation.